# Android Editext line color

Tags: android, colors, android-edittext, themes

I am currently styling an EditText.
What I want is the color of the EditText line to be of one color when not selected and of another when focus/activated.

With appcompat 22.2.0 and build tools 22.0.1 and using custom theme for the EditText here what I see :

Normal :

[image]

Selected :

[image: editext issue]

I would like the line color to be replaced not overlayed.

Here is my EditText xml :

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTest"
    android:theme="@style/MyEditTextTheme"                       
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
```

And the style :

```
<style name="MyEditTextTheme">    
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/color_light_blue</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/color_light_orange</item> 
</style>
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a drawable similar to this, just add in a selector for adding a selected/unselected state:

(Basically what I'm doing is making a square with a border of X color, then I create a square of the background color but shift it up by the width of the border so the bottom one won't be covered but the left, right, top will be covered)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/your_color" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:bottom="2dp">
        <shape

            android:shape="rectangle">

            <solid android:color="@color/background_color" />
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/background_color_to_mask_the_square"/>

        </shape>
    </item>


</layer-list>
```

Comment: Nice solution. I will use it even if I'd prefer using Themes for readability.

Comment: You could make this into a theme, just create an edit_text_theme and add this as the background drawable

Comment: My comment was not accurate. I don't know if I'm superstitious, but I don't like creating custom drawables when I just want to change a color and that the system provides such methods (for maintainability). However if what I've mentionned is an Android bug, your solution is a neat workaround.

Comment: If you end up using my method please mark it <3 otherwise sorry i couldn't help you out more!